How to change a TYPO3 composer installation into a classic installation?
I got a web server with an old composer installation for TYPO3 (V8).
There is no working composer (the PHP version is to old for the modern composer version) and there is no repository for the old TYPO3.
As I need to install an extension to fix the site before updating is done I need to change the composer installation into a classic installation to add the extension by copying into typo3conf/ext/.
What needs to be changed?
files/folders to delete? files to be modified?

You can download a suitable older composer version as a phar, and use that. That would be way easier than converting an install and moving several dozen directories around...?

If you do not want to use a older composer Version as suggested by Garvin Hicking, then i would do the following:

Download and install a clean TYPO3 8 Version and make it available under a subdomain. Assuming you are not setting the system up locally.

Go through the Extension-Manager and install all extensions in the correct version in your (new) TYPO3. You could either download your custom extensions or move them directly on the server.

Replace the LocalConf and AdditionalConf in the typo3conf folder.

Replace the Fileadmin

Delete all tables in the new TYPO3 and import the Database from your old system.


Now you should have the same system in legacy mode.
I would suggest to do a DB compare and some system checks. Just to be sure.

An alternative approach to the question itself is just to install composer on the server. As long as SSH access exists, this is an approach that doesn't require any special access rights.
The most simple way would be to cd into the directory where composer shall be executed and follow the download instructions on getcomposer.org.
A slightly more advanced approach would be to install it with these guidelines. At this link a bit deeper is also the global installation explained -- which allows to use composer in any directory without having to know the path of the phar-file.
Especially for the global installation you can consider making a symlink composer linking to composer.phar. Then you can use it easier and never have to think about the suffix always.
Furthermore, even if you never have SSH access you can theoretically note the commands in a PHP file, i.e. for installing a TYPO3 distribution or anything else. As long as there are no dependency problems in a composer.json file of a project, the installation could be just triggered by calling a website on the server. Note that this a "hack" and a security risk if the file stays with public access on the server. If you (have to) decide for this way, be sure to remove those files directly after the work, and at best secure the access to the website by password during the work.

As I'm no admin on the server I need to install it in my user space. And I need to make my own repositories for all the extensions and the old TYPO3 as I have no access to the original repositories.

Of course in the user space, there is nothing wrong with it. The "Repositories" can be represented just by a local folder "packages" where all the extensions can be included. It's quite common to have this solution during development. For private repositories on gihub, gitlab or anything else Satis is one option, you could consider it, when there aren't many changes to expect anymore in the extensions.
